# How does $\frac12X_{n}+1 \leq \frac12X_{n+1} + 1. $ imply $X_{n+1} ≤ X_{n+2}$

Tags: analysis

I'm reading my math textbook about induction and part of a specific question is to prove, "if we have $X_n \leq X_{n+1}$, then it follows that $X_{n+1} \leq X_{n+2}$." The textbook then goes on to say "Starting from the induction hypothesis $X_n \leq X_{n+1}$, we can multiply across the inequality by $\frac12$ and add $1$ to get
$$\frac12(X_n) + 1 \leq \frac12 X_{n+1} + 1$$ which is precisely the desired conclusion $$X_{n+1} \leq X_{n+2}.$$

However, I don't really understand how $X_{n+1} \leq X_{n+2}$ was derived from $$\frac12X_{n}+1 \leq \frac12X_{n+1} + 1. $$

Picture of the exercise:
[image: Picture of the exercise]

Answer (score 0):

It proves that $\frac{1}{2}x_{n}+1\leq\frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}+1$. Subtracting $1$ from both sides yields $\frac{1}{2}x_{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}$. Then, multiplying both sides by $2$ gives $x_{n}\leq x_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $x_n$ is defined using the iteration

$$x_{n+1} = \frac12 x_n + 1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Hence,

$$x_{n+1} = \frac12 x_n + 1$$ and $$x_{n+2} = \frac12 x_{n+1} + 1$$

Since $\frac12 x_n + 1 \leq \frac12 x_{n+1} + 1$, we have

$$x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$A \le B \iff \frac 12A + 1 \le \frac 12 B + 1$.

That shouldn't be surprising you just do the same thing to both sides of the inequatity.  As you never multiply or divide by anything less than or equal to $0$ the inequality never "flips"

So if $A = X_{n}$ and $B= X_{n+1}$ and you *know already* that for *that* particular $n$ that

$\frac 12 X_n + 1 \le \frac 12 X_{n+1}+1$    (I need to stress this: You *know* this part because you figured it out somewhere else.  *I* do not know where are how.  That was part of the text.)

***IF***  $\frac 12 X_n + 1 \le \frac 12 X_{n+1}+1$ then subtract $1$ from both sides to get

$\frac 12 X_n \le \frac 12 X_{n+1}$ then multiply  both sides by $2$ to get

$X_n \le X_{n+1}$.